# How to display the parsed JSON data in android

Tags: android

I have parsed the JSON data and storing the parsed JSON data into ArrayList HashMap with the key value ,when I want to display the parsed data I am getting only the last value of the parsed Data rest all data are not displayed for reference

```
public HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
create HASHmap then arraylist
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
void parsing(JSONObject json)
    {
        String id="";
        String countryn="";
        try
        {
            countryobj = json.getJSONArray("country_details");

     for(int i = 0;i<countryobj.length(); i++)
     {
         JSONObject items = countryobj.getJSONObject(i);

         Log.e("i","value==="+i);

         if(items.has("countryid"))
         {
             id = items.getString("countryid");
             map.put("countryid",id);
             Log.e("id","valueID==="+id);
         }
         if(items.has("country"))
         {
             countryn= items.getString("country");
             map.put("country",countryn);
             Log.e("counyrt","valueName==="+countryn);

         }
         contactList.add(i,map);
         Log.e("lisvaluet","val--"+i +contactList.get(i));


     }



    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception

            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

in Log I am getting `only 08-20 12:13:45.830: E/--ID---(654): value--{countryid=275, country=Palestinian Territory} with 269 times` can any help me out where I am doing wrong in storing the parsed data , I am stuck here.

Comment: Thanks hardik just for alligning my Questions

Comment: http://72.29.76.194/~golfcash/iphone//country.php this is the uRL of my JSON

Comment: this is the Http Request Class where i passs the URL

Comment: Show me that activity code where you show that data

Comment: allList=handlr.parsing(json);
       HashMap<String, String>mapData;
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>allList=null;
        for(int i=0;i<allList.size();i++)
        {
         mapData = allList.get(i);
         id = mapData.get("countryid").toString();
         Log.e("--ID---","value--"+id);
         
         mapData = allList.get(i);
         countryname = mapData.get("country").toString();
         Log.e("--Name---","value--"+countryname);
        }

Comment: Hello Chirag I have passe the URL from my Activity and then parsed in another class and trying to display in other actiivty the parsed data

Comment: you have to make that arraylist static so you can get anywhere you want using classname.ListName

Comment: yes I have made it that one also but i a getting the same last parsed data repeated ,just now i had changed to the return type with Arraylist do you have th sample code snippet for parsing and displaying the parsed data

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
private JSONObject[] items;

JSONArray countryobj = json.getJSONArray("country_details");
items = new JSONObject[countryobj.length()];

for(int i=0, i < countryobj.length(); i++)
{
    items[i] = countryobj.optJSONObject(i);
    id = items[i].getString("countryid");
    map.put("countryid",id);

    countryn= items[i].getString("country");
    map.put("country",countryn);

    contactList.add(i,map);
}
```

[image]

Comment: hello Chirag thanks for the reply but still same iam geting same can you run the code on your side and let me know

Comment: @shvivek , i Got all the country name with this code of parsing.

Comment: i am also getting all the id and countryname and when i save in contactList.app(map) and try to retrive the parsed data i am getting only CountryId and countryname 275 and palestine....are you able to display the parsed data please help me out iam stuck

Comment: Hi even I am getting all the data , but when I want to display the store data of Arraylist in some other activities then I am getting only 1 value that is repeating .. same countryid and same countryname